# Bootstrap put checkboxes into 3 evenly spaced columns and centered within form

Tags: html, css, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling to set my checkboxes in the below form into 3 evenly spaced columns and centered perfectly within the form. It currently looks as below...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3Lpg.png)

But, I want it to look like...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh7U8.png)

HTML:

`

```
            <form action="/signup" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        name="firstName"
                        id="first-name"
                        class="form-control" 
                        placeholder="First Name"    
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        name="surname"
                        id="surname"
                        class="form-control" 
                        placeholder="Surname"    
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input 
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        id="email" 
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Email"
                    />
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                </div>
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend>Pick your favourite 3 things</legend>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                      <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input class="form-check-input mr-2" type="checkbox" value="">
                        Option 1
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input mr-2" type="checkbox" value="">
                          Option 2
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input mr-2" type="checkbox" value="">
                          Option 3
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input mr-2" type="checkbox" value="">
                          Option 4
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input mr-2" type="checkbox" value="">
                          Option 5
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input mr-2" type="checkbox" value="">
                          Option 6
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input mr-2" type="checkbox" value="">
                          Option 7
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input mr-2" type="checkbox" value="">
                          Option 8
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                          <input class="form-check-input mr-2" type="checkbox" value="">
                          Option 9
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Do it!</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: I updated the answer and added labels.

Answer (score 0):

```html
...
<legend>Pick your 3 favourite things</legend>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        Option 1
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        Option 2
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        Option 3
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        Option 4
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        Option 5
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        Option 6
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        Option 7
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        Option 8
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        Option 9
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bf4vtzry/1/

Comment: Thank you Simeon. It doesn't work when you add labels to the checkboxes, they just stack on top of one another.

Comment: I added a JSFiddle and it works fine unless the screen is not wide enough: they they'll stack on top of each other. How wide is your screen?

Comment: In your JSFiddle you have put the label and checkbox separate, whereas I was putting the checkbox within the label tag. I want them to be in 3 columns on large and medium screens, and responsive so that when on smaller screens they then stack. Also, when putting in labels with different character lengths, they no longer remain aligned.

Comment: Alright, I updated the code and the fiddle. You may need to change `col-md-4` to e.g. `col-sm-4` to match your desired breakpoint.

Comment: That is excellent man, your help is much appreciated. Is there a way to keep the checkboxes aligned when the texts are different character lengths?